# Как правильно посчитать сумму String?

Tags: java, mysql, android-studio, строки

Передаю в базу SQL данные которые вводит пользователь editext "название" доход" "расход" "итог"  нужно  вычесть из дохода расход и отправить в итог .

}

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    // создаем объект для данных
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    // получаем данные из полей ввода
    String name = etName.getText().toString();
    String   income = etIncome.getText().toString();
    String  expenses = etExpenses.getText().toString();
    //etIncome.
   // String total = result()
    //int i = (income - expenses);
    //int total = i;

    // подключаемся к БД
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
   // SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();


    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnAdd:
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Добавлено в MYREPORT: ---");
            // подготовим данные для вставки в виде пар: наименование столбца - значение

            cv.put("name", name);
            cv.put("income", income);
            cv.put("expenses", expenses);
           // cv.put("total");
            // вставляем запись и получаем ее ID
            long rowID = db.insert("MYREPORT", null, cv);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "row inserted, ID = " + rowID);
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Вроде нашел такой ответ, можно попробовать изменить тип,а потом уже математически вычесть из дохода расход .

1. Измените тип ввода (в вашем EditTextполе) в файле макета на android:inputType="number"

2: использовать int a = Integer.parseInt(yourEditTextObject.getText().toString());